# In Spock, how do I test that a static method was called from another static method?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

Here is my class:

```java
class Application {
    public static void main(){
        System.out.println("main called");
        otherMethod();
    }

    public static void otherMethod(){
        System.out.println("otherMethod called");
    }
}
```

Here is my spock test

```rb
def "Expect that Application.otherMethod() is called"(){
    given:
    def app = new Application() 

    when:
    Application.main()

    then:
    1 * Application.otherMethod()
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I love Spock and also use interaction testing, but it is being overused by most developers. Just because you _can_ use it it does not mean you _should_ all the time. Even if you _could_ do that with static methods, why would you? Why would you want to test the inner wiring of your application? What value does such a test have? IMO interactions should be tested only if they are vital to your implemented class or design pattern, e.g. if you want to check that for an observer pattern the notifications sent by the subject to its registered observers actually take place as expected.

Comment: The technical answer to your question is: Spock can only mock static method calls or check interactions on them for Groovy classes using `GroovyMock` or `GroovySpy`. For Java classes the mocks behave like normal Spock mocks. If you do want to tread that path - and I urge you not to but to refactor! - you can use PowerMock from within Spock. But PowerMock usage is a code smell IMO. So just don't. Go refactor!

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Static methods should not have visible side effects (ideally, they should be pure functions), and it doesn't matter to the client *how* they're implemented.

In your simplistic case, you move the call for `otherMethod()` into a constructor for `Application` and call `new Application()` from your `main`.

Comment: what if I cant use an instance?

Comment: @BrianJosephSpinos Are you literally attempting to test `main`?

Comment: I need 100% code coverage, so yes, every method call, every branch, every line.

Comment: Your `main` should be reduced to a "launch application instance", and then you should push back on that single case. Testing the launcher *does not make sense*.

Comment: Even If I do so, I would be testing another class with the same characteristics: a class with a static method, that calls another static method, how would I do that?

Comment: Whatever it is, *you don't do that*. De-static it. If it's a pure function, then test only the inputs and outputs. If it has side effects, it shouldn't be static.